# c++ cambiar valor variable con atajo de tecla

Tags: c++

Tengo un error en c++ estoy escribiendo un codigo que al tocar una tecla cambie el valor de un boolean como si fuese un interruptor el codigo es este

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool status = false;
    while (true) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8) && status == false) {
            status = true;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8) && status == true) {
            status = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Saludos, ¿qué error recibes? Te recomiendo mirar [ask] para obtener más información de cómo preguntar y así poder obtener mejores respuestas. ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow!

Comment: Puedes simplificar los dos ifs en uno así: `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8)) status = !status;`

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que el error que estas recibiendo es que no siempre se cambia el valor de `status` esto es porque `GetAsyncKeyState` detecta cuando la tecla esta presionada, y como estas dentro de un `while` loop, cuando presionas la tecla por aunque sea un segundo, las instrucciones del `if` se repiten decenas, si no es que cientas veces. Lo que debes hacer es anadir otro `while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8));` dentro de tu `if`, para que asi las instrucciones solo se repitan una vez, y mientras igas presionando la tecla, el codigo solo se quede esperando. Anadiendo tambien el consejo de @Mateo para simplificar tu codigo, quedaria algo asi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool status = false;
    
    while (true) {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8)){
            status = !status;
            
            while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8));
        }
    }
}
```